# bootstrap 3 - place a search input on the right before the icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="profile.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to place a search input on the right but before the icons. So I add a form:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>      
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="profile.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That got it:

[image]

Instead of (the picture made by paint):

[image]

What should be done to make it as the second picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
             </div>      
            </form>
       </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="profile.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move form tag below UI tag.
Like this one

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="profile.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>      
  </form>  
</div>
```

Comment: When you use navbar-right it uses float style. So if multiple elements has float style, then the last one element with float style comes first. In your case UI and form both has navbar-right style, so the element coming at last will appear first